# JWT Authentication Service

Tags: c#, object-oriented, authentication, jwt

Recently I've built a service at my work to generate tokens with JWT (JSON Web Token) "protocol", I would like to show you the code and to get comments from you if that's good enough and if there are things to improve.

The service contains 2 folders and 4 classes.

1. Models Folder

   - IAuthContainerModel (Interface)
   - JWTContainerModel (Implementation)
2. Managers Folder

   - IAuthService (Interface)
   - JWTService (Implementation)

---

- IAuthContainerModel

Code:

```
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace AuthenticationService.Models
{
    public interface IAuthContainerModel
    {
        #region Members
        string SecretKey { get; set; }
        string SecurityAlgorithm { get; set; }

        Claim[] Claims { get; set; }
        int ExpireMinutes { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

- JWTContainerModel

Code:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace AuthenticationService.Models
{
    public class JWTContainerModel : IAuthContainerModel
    {
        #region Public Methods
        public int ExpireMinutes { get; set; } = 10080; // 7 days.
        public string SecretKey { get; set; } = "TW9zaGVFcmV6UHJpdmF0ZUtleQ=="; // This secret key should be moved to some configurations outter server.
        public string SecurityAlgorithm { get; set; } = SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature;

        public Claim[] Claims { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

ExpireMinutes is a default value and SecretKey is also a default value, of course the secret key will be in the configurations section inside the server

- IAuthService

Code:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AuthenticationService.Models;

namespace AuthenticationService.Managers
{
    public interface IAuthService
    {
        string SecretKey { get; set; }

        bool IsTokenValid(string token);
        string GenerateToken(IAuthContainerModel model);
        IEnumerable<Claim> GetTokenClaims(string token);
    }
}
```

- JWTService

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AuthenticationService.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace AuthenticationService.Managers
{
    public class JWTService : IAuthService
    {
        #region Members
        /// <summary>
        /// The secret key we use to encrypt out token with.
        /// </summary>
        public string SecretKey { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public JWTService(string secretKey)
        {
            SecretKey = secretKey;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Validates whether a given token is valid or not, and returns true in case the token is valid otherwise it will return false;
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsTokenValid(string token)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                throw new ArgumentException("Given token is null or empty.");

            TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = GetTokenValidationParameters();

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            try
            {
                ClaimsPrincipal tokenValid = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates token by given model.
        /// Validates whether the given model is valid, then gets the symmetric key.
        /// Encrypt the token and returns it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns>Generated token.</returns>
        public string GenerateToken(IAuthContainerModel model)
        {
            if (model == null || model.Claims == null || model.Claims.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Arguments to create token are not valid.");

            SecurityTokenDescriptor securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(model.Claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(model.ExpireMinutes)),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(GetSymmetricSecurityKey(), model.SecurityAlgorithm)
            };

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            SecurityToken securityToken = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
            string token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

            return token;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Receives the claims of token by given token as string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Pay attention, one the token is FAKE the method will throw an exception.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="token"></param>
        /// <returns>IEnumerable of claims for the given token.</returns>
        public IEnumerable<Claim> GetTokenClaims(string token)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                throw new ArgumentException("Given token is null or empty.");

            TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = GetTokenValidationParameters();

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            try
            {
                ClaimsPrincipal tokenValid = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
                return tokenValid.Claims;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private SecurityKey GetSymmetricSecurityKey()
        {
            byte[] symmetricKey = Convert.FromBase64String(SecretKey);
            return new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey);
        }

        private TokenValidationParameters GetTokenValidationParameters()
        {
            return new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = GetSymmetricSecurityKey()
            };
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

What do you say about this code? is it implemented correctly? would you fix it in some way? I will be happy to hear your opinions!

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me, I just a few minor suggestions.

> ```
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>     throw ex;
> }
> ```

You probably left this in by accident, but you're better off without a catch block if all you're going to do is re-throw.  And if you are going to keep this block, `throw;` is always preferable to `throw ex;`

I question the wisdom of having a "default" key specified in the code.  It seems to me that it should always read from outside and complain loudly if it fails.  With a usable default key, it opens the possibility that it could use the wrong key without you knowing about it.